# Setting DisplayMemberPath to a Dictionary's Structure Value Member

Tags: wpf, listbox, binding, structure

I have a listbox that has its `ItemsSource` set to a `Dictionary(Of String, ColumnMetadata)`. `ColumnMetadata` is a structure. I can easily get the `DisplayMemberPath` to show the keys by setting it to `"Key"`, but I can't figure out how to get it to show a member of my structure.

I've tried settings `DisplayMemberPath` to `"{Binding LocalizedColumn}"`, `"Value.LocalizedColumn"`, `"LocalizedColumn"`, `"{Value.LocalizedColumn}"` and none of those works. I just get a bunch of blank lines in my listbox.

All I'm looking to accomplish is to get the data in to the listbox. I'm not concerned with any updates back to the dictionary and the dictionary won't be updated after the list is populated.

The code I have now is activated at runtime:

        `lstDatabaseColumns.ItemsSource = ImportData.GetAddressFieldData
        lstDatabaseColumns.DisplayMemberPath = "Value.LocalizedColumn"
        lstDatabaseColumns.SelectedValuePath = "Key"`

My structure looks like:

    `Public Structure ColumnMetadata
        Dim LocalizedColumn As String
        Dim Description As String
    End Structure`

I'm getting the following message in my output window:

`` System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'LocalizedColumn' property not found on 'object' ''ColumnMetadata' (HashCode=1118531966)'. BindingExpression:Path=Value.LocalizedColumn; DataItem='KeyValuePair`2' (HashCode=-1578744570); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') ``

Comment: the correct `DisplayMemberPath` is "Value.LocalizedColumn". If it doesn't work, check the output window in VS for binding errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code to a class and Overrode the `ToString()` function:

    `Public Class ColumnMetadata
        Public LocalizedColumn As String
        Public Description As String`

```
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return LocalizedColumn
    End Function
End Class
```

Then I set my runtime assignments to:

        `lstDatabaseColumns.ItemsSource = ImportData.GetAddressFieldData
        lstDatabaseColumns.DisplayMemberPath = "Value"
        lstDatabaseColumns.SelectedValuePath = "Key"`

Now everything is working. When a user clicks on an item in the list box and they want to do something with the other items in the class, for example assign it to a text box, I've implemented this code:

`lblColumnDescription.Text = DirectCast(lstDatabaseColumns.SelectedItem, KeyValuePair(Of String, ImportData.ColumnMetadata)).Value.Description`

Using that method I can now access any part of the class or the key of the dictionary.

I'm still interested in knowing what to set `DisplayMemberPath` to in order to show a specific member of a structure.

Answer (score 2):

I tested `DisplayMemberPath="Value.MyValue"` and it worked well.

The sample data was:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyValue { get; set; }
}

public Dictionary<int, MyClass> Data
 {
     get
     {
         Dictionary<int, MyClass> data = new Dictionary<int, MyClass>();
         data[0] = new MyClass { MyValue = "A" };
         data[1] = new MyClass { MyValue = "B" };

         return data;
     }
 }
```

Xaml:

```
 <ListBox DisplayMemberPath="Value.MyValue" x:Name="lst" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=local, Path=Data}" />
```

Good luck!

Comment: I just converted my structure to a class and it still doesn't work. Does it matter that I'm doing all my binding at runtime? (I've updated my question to include my code.)

Comment: The OP used a struct, not a class... Perhaps that's why it's not working for him, although I doubt it changes anything. Did you try with a struct as well ?